# get islamic data and georgian date in specific format in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i want to get the current date in format like this 24 February 2014 . i want
also get Islamic date in the same format as 5 jumada al-awwal 1436
how can i do that i saw other thing but most care about integer components.
i wrote this code which just get components

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

NSLog(@"%@",components);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

i used this to Islamic date

```
NSCalendar *islamicCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar]; 
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
[islamicCalendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&today interval:NULL forDate:today]; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setCalendar:islamicCalendar];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
 //english output 
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSString * islamicDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"%@", islamicDateString);
```

Comment: why do you use the `currentCalendar` for the Islamic date? the current one is mostly the _Gregorian_ calendar on the devices. it would be more reasonable to use explicitly a specific `NSIslamicCalendar` or `NSIslamicCivilCalendar` calendar, hm?

Comment: i used the first code for georgian and second code for islamic .

Comment: but how make them in the format i want?

Comment: Consider: `localizedStringFromDate:` and `dateFormatFromTemplate:`.

Comment: could you put full code for any of them where i write localizedStringFromDate